# Why will myfigurecollection.net not load properly in Tor browser?

Tags: website

myfigurecollection.net will not load properly in Tor browser (except for the login page for some reason - https://secure.myfigurecollection.net/signs.php?mode=in&ln=en). Is this a bug in Tor browser? I have had no problems like this with any other site using Tor.

Answer (score 3):

Because their CDN, *s1.tsuki-board.net*, blocks Tor connections with a captcha.

Theoretically if you visit http://s1.tsuki-board.net alone and solve the captcha, you should have the home site working. It usually works this way, but I don't know why it is not for this website. Static contents still return 403 when loaded on the main site, while loads fine alone.